# Thank you Dr. Buffy, Academia.SE's GOAT

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, Buffy [officially](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) became Academia.SE's user with the greatest all-time reputation score: nearly **169K** reputation! In just 2.5 years, Buffy has authored a stunning **3,742 answers** and earned **48** gold badges, among many other positive contributions.

Academia.SE is lucky to have many highly active users who make many excellent contributions, but Buffy's sustained level of involvement is really unprecedented -- this is our stack's version of [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/). So thanks for all the work, and we look forward to 169K more points!

**TL;DR:**

[image]

Comment: Congrats! Buffy is often the first face a user will see when they come to Academia.se, and it's a pleasure to know that they are welcome with such friendly, positively inclined messages!

Comment: congratulations!

Comment: Congrats on your new [t-shirt and socks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/)!

Comment: Gosh. Oh, and woof-woof.

Comment: Hah love the puppy too!

Comment: Congrats @Buffy. Well deserved for all your efforts and contribution to make the site a clean and happening place.

Comment: Is there any way to have the money that might go toward swag to be donated to some charitable organization? Preferably hunger related or similar?

Comment: @Buffy Not officially. Maybe you can try to ask when you receive the email for the swag from SE. Stack Exchange donates every year to a number of selected charities on behalf of moderators (an initiative called [Stack Gives Back](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/20/10-years-of-stack-giving-back/)), and maybe they can add that contribution.

Comment: Congratulations Dr Buffy :)

Comment: Congrats @Buffy!

Comment: Congrats@Buffy.

Comment: Well done, @Buffy!  You've answered me directly once or twice, and I've certainly read many of your other answers. Thank-you!

Comment: Less than 3 years later, Buffy has indeed achieved 169K more points. At this rate, he'll go over 500K by the end of 2026.

Answer (score 3):

Dr Buffy is at 308,000 and counting!

Comment: Indeed. More than all four mods combined. My challenge of "169K more points" will probably be achieved before the end of the year.